# Find if string contains at least 2 characters similar to another? C#

Tags: c#, string, compare, contains

I need a method to check if a string contains one or more similar characters to another. I dont want to find all strings containing the letter "D".
For example, if I have a string "Christopher" and want to see if "Chris" is contained in "Christopher", I want that to return. However, if I want to see if "Candy" is in the string "Christopher", I wont want it to return just because it has a "C" in common.

I have tried the .Contains() method but cant give that rules for 2 or more similar characters and I have thought about using regular expressions but that might be a bit over kill. The similar letters must be next to eachother.

Thank you :)

Comment: Must the letters be adjacent?

Comment: yes, that have to be right next to eachother

Comment: @user....need a little more info.  Would you want "Cp" to return if looking at "Christopher"?  And what about "Chrx" when searching "Christopher"?

Comment: If "Chrx" was compared, that could return. "Cp" shouldnt be returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks for each 2-character-gram of `s1` and looks for it in `s2`.

```
string s1 = "Chrx";
string s2 = "Christopher";
IsMatchOn2Characters(s1, s2);

static bool IsMatchOn2Characters(string a, string b)
{
    string s1 = a.ToLowerInvariant();
    string s2 = b.ToLowerInvariant();

    for (int i = 0; i < s1.Length - 1; i++)
    {
       if (s2.IndexOf(s1.Substring(i,2)) >= 0)
          return true; // match
    }

    return false; // no match
}
```

Comment: how do I make it insensitive?

Comment: is there a way to modify this to start at any point in the string? @agent-j

Comment: Start at a certain point in which string?  "Christopher", or the search string "Chrx"?

Comment: "Christopher" to see if "Chrx" is similar

Comment: At present, it searches the entire string.  ("Chris" matches "Christopher", "ch", "hr", "ri", "is").  Can you show a specific example.

Comment: well for example, if searching "Christopher" for "Atchris", would that return true?

Comment: Yes.  `CH` from Christopher would match "ch" from "Atchris".  This is because of the `.IndexOf() >= 0`.  It matches anywhere in the string.

Comment: @agent....in the for loop, I think it needs to say "i < s1.Length - 2" since we're doing a substring on 2 characters. Yes?

Comment: yes i think so, May I also ask by the way, what if the substring is bigger than the string we are searching in?

Comment: @MikeTWebb, to do one item at a time, we use `for (int i=0; i<s1.length; i++)`, so to do two entries, I think we are safe to do `for (int i=0; i < s1.length - 1; i++)`.

Comment: @user1290653, the for loop goes through all of `s1`, and the IndexOf goes through all of `s2`, so yes, it supports small and large strings.

Answer (score 1):

This looks a lot like a [longest common substring problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem). This can be solved easily using DP in O(m*n).

If you are not worried about performance and don't really want to implement this, you can also go with the brute force solution of searching every substring of s1 into s2.